# Android Development - Dealing with XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I have been learning android development and I am still new to this.

I have already designed many apps for iOS.

**Is there a better way to have my layouts as easy as iOS?**

because in iOS I only have to drag and move it wherever I want . Where in android I have to insert tables and edit XMLs, which I find very confusing and not flexible to deal with.

I have read and watched many tutorial and still find it a bit difficult to deal with

Thanks

Comment: Don't make comparison between 2 platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. The long answer is that this is how it's done on Android, and it's much more flexible than the iOS method. Just imagine making Android app the iOS way and support screen sizes such as 240x320, 320x480, 480x800, 480x854, 540x960, 600x1024, 720x1280...and so on, and it's easy to realize that it would be an impossible task. This is almost certainly why Apple went with "Retina Display" with exactly 2x the pixel density and exact same screen dimension (3.5") - because doing anything else would mean that all the apps would need to be designed specifically for the new screen instead of just providing images with a @2x postfix.

So, instead of absolute positioning and sizing like the iOS, XML is used in Android where designers are tasked to come up with one or more layouts that can support this diverse range of screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a layout editor for Android that you can use in Eclipse. Is that what you're looking for?

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html#graphical-editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse Layout Editor for Drag and Drop with absolute layout. But using absolute layout is not a good practice because in iOS screen size is fixed for all device but in android there are different screen size device are available and if you design a layout considering a single screen size it will be messed on another screen size device. You must follow the norms to create a layout go through this link for more detail.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Comment: What you said about absolute positioning is right but, In eclipse graphical layout editor, you can use other layouts too :)

Comment: Yes but you can not Drag any component anywhere on screen except Relative Layout. Absolute Layout is easy but not good for practical use.